# How to test SSL is set up and configured correctly on dev?

Tags: testing, ssl, certificate

I am moving a site from one server to a new server. Currently the new server is the development site and is accessed via IP.

I have copied and set up the SSL on the new server but there doesn't seem to be anyway of testing that the SSL is properly installed until I point the domain.

Is there a way I can test that the SSL it setup and configured correctly before I point the domain?

Ideally I'd like to launch the site and know that everything is working correctly!

Thanks

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try adding the new IP address for the host to your `/etc/hosts` (or wherever Windows stores the `hosts` file; look in `C:\Windows\System32\hosts` as a starting point) file on your client. It's just like updating DNS for a single machine.

Don't forget to remove the entry after you're done testing.

Answer (score 2):

When you set up that entry in the hosts file it should have the form:

```
"IP address of dev server" "olddomain.com"
```

and when you remove the entry you can simply comment it out with a "#" at the beginning of the line